# Unity Facebook integration. Keystore file missing

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using the latest version of Unity. I am trying to integrate the latest version of Facebook SDK into my app. In the Unity editor where facebook settings are displayed, I get an error saying that my keystore file is missing.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4cXS.jpg)

I have Openssl installed and added to environment variables. I have JDK 1.8 installed and added to environment variables. I have JRE 1.8 installed and added to environment variables.

Obviously, I have a keyfile that I have generated using Unity. Please help me in what I am doing wrong. There was one similar discussion, but the original question was different. That's why I posted this here. Also the answers there are outdated as it was 4 years old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The facebookSDK is looking for your debug.keystore which should be present in your user folder like so:

> C:\Users\userName\.android\debug.keystore

To create a new debug.keystore use the following command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

more explainations about debug.keystore here: [What is the use of debug.keystore in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838636/what-is-the-use-of-debug-keystore-in-android)
and  [How can I create a keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore)

Comment: But I already have a keyfile. Is it compulsory that there should be a debug keyfile present in the PC even-though we have a keyfile? This answer atually solved my issue for now.

Comment: Same goes for the openSSL error... I wasted a lot of time because of thoses errors. Eventually the facebookSDK will throw a post-build error event if your apk was built just fine.
I dont remember if the warning you linked above causes the same issues, but it might be harmless anyway depending on your configuration

Answer (score 0):

For anyone whos debug is produced, and is at the appropriate location but  Facebook isn't detecting it. Try creating a new keystore file (you don't need to use it anywhere but just create one). By doing so you will force FB SDK to look for key forcefully.